# Close window after *STYLE* story board completes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Style that targets a Window, I do some basic fade-in / fade out and Stop / Seek through the story board and the Window behaves how I want it. I then noticed the Window isn't actually being closed on the fade out. The relevant part of the style is:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="sbFadeInFadeOut">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:01" From="0.0" To="0.8" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:01.5" From="0.8" To="0.0" BeginTime="00:00:04" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
```

So I fade in the window and then after a while I fade it out. There are some other scenarios where I want this animation to go and there are some where I just want to flat out close the window.

Anyways, at the end of this story board, the opacity is 0, but the window is actually still open.

I tried setting the Completed event of the second animation to "Close", but got:

The event 'Completed' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead. Line 225 Position 123.

I kind of got it working by adding a callback to the Opacity DP and waiting for it to be 0, but that seems like a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be done by creating an attached property which closes the `Window` when changed to `true` by the `StoryBoard`'s last `Animation`:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Name="sbFadeInFadeOut">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:01" From="0.0" To="0.8" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:01.5" From="0.8" To="0.0" BeginTime="00:00:04" />
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:WindowAttachedProperties.IsClosed)" BeginTime="00:00:05.5">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And the attached property is defined as:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApplication.AttachedProperties
{
    public class WindowAttachedProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsClosedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsClosed", typeof(bool), typeof(WindowAttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), PropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            var window = dependencyObject as Window;
            var isClosed = window?.GetValue(IsClosedProperty) as bool?;

            if (window != null && isClosed.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                window.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void SetIsClosed(DependencyObject element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsClosedProperty, value);
        }

        public static bool GetIsClosed(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (bool) element.GetValue(IsClosedProperty);
        }
    }
}
```